# check is radio element checked in ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, response

I have ajax response containing two radio element.i want to check if radio element is checked in response.

I m using below code to check radio status but not working.

```
  $('#input[type=radio]').each(function(){
 alert($(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

as i know  this is not working due to  ajax response. but how to fire js code to check even in ajax resoponse.

any help would be much appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).find('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
      //your code
   }
});
```

Comment: This is not working my content(radio button) is loaded dynamically.

Comment: Are these checkboxes dynamically being added to page?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle because this code works fine for me @Freedom

Comment: This work when dom is loaded but my radio is updated dynamically using ajax response so..

Comment: This code can works when your radio is loaded using ajax response @Freedom

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#input[type=radio]').each(function(){
 if($(this).is(':checked')){

 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use prop

```
  $('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
 alert($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

and #input only if your radio have id="input". if you want check all radio, could be only

```
input[type=radio]
```

as the example

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is your selector which contains `#` for id:

```
$('#input[type=radio]')
//-^------------------------# is used to select an id not the tags
```

try this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
    alert(this.checked); // returns "true" if checked/ "false" if not checked
});
```

Comment: but you have not mentioned the event on which you are trying to loop.

Comment: currently it fire on live(click) event but actually  i want to check it when radio button update(render) through ajax response.

Comment: @Freedom so you mean to say you have updated your html content whichi have some radios cheked or unchecked and that you want to see.

Comment: If that is the case then you have to update the html content first then after that you have to loop through and BTW if you have a latest jQuery then `.live()` wont work instead you have to go with `.on()`